# Key-less elements in ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, config, custom-configuration

When you inherit ConfigurationElementCollection:

```
public class Directories : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    ...
}
```

`ConfigurationElementCollection` requires an implementation for `GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement)`.

But I don't care about keys since I have a custom configuration section like this:

```
<directorySection>
  <directories>
    <directory pickUpDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\PickUp\0" dropOffDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\DropOff\0"/>
    <directory pickUpDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\PickUp\0" dropOffDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\DropOff\0"/>
    <directory pickUpDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\PickUp\1" dropOffDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\DropOff\1"/>
    <directory pickUpDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\PickUp\2" dropOffDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\DropOff\2"/>
  </directories>
</directorySection>
```

It can have multiple elements, and each element is key-less, and this structure should allow for duplicates (as above). So what should I do in this case?

Comment: Then don't inherit `ConfigurationElementCollection` :) Use another way to parse/generate your xml.

Comment: @L.B I was going to go down that road initially, but now its like I have no other choice; nothing supports this out of the box with custom .config sections?

Comment: Have you tried just reading your application config file for your custom section and deserializing it into whatever class suits your needs?

Comment: @Louis I think L.B. suggested this

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood @L.B answer, I felt it was more generic. Now that I read mine, its actually not so different. Anyway, you dont need to implement ConfigurationElement at all as long as you know the XML structure. You could always read ApplicationSettings["directories"] using Linq XML for example. Maybe I fail to see your requirements?

Comment: @Louis That's a good idea; I'll give that a shot

Comment: @Louis It actually gets so much more complicated...maybe if you provide a link so that I can better understand how you would do it this way? But...the problem I am facing now is this: when you define a custom configuration section, the `<section>` tag requires both `name` and `type` attributes, and since I am loading all of this from a Windows service, if the `type` name is not available in my assembly and/or it does not exactly match the structure of the XAML in my .config file, it will crash my service on startup with a `System.TypeLoadException`.

Comment: Put it this way, guys, in the end, does this mean I have to parse the entire .config file myself? Because all roads lead to a dead end except parsing the entire .config myself and essentially making my own `ConfigurationManager` implementation.

Comment: I'm going to stop jumping through ridiculous hoops now. I went with using `var document = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);`, and then parsing that for what I need using LINQ queries and such.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [ObjectIDGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SchedulerTaskItem), AddItemName = "Task")]
public class SchedulerTaskCollection: ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    private static readonly ObjectIDGenerator idGenerator = new ObjectIDGenerator();

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new SchedulerTaskItem();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        bool firstTime;
        return idGenerator.GetId(element, out firstTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *very* old question, but I just ran into this issue.

Here's the general data structure I'm working with, though I'll probably tweak the actual implementation as it goes:

```
<filter>
    <group type="and|or|not">
        <condition field="..." operator="..." value="...">
        <group type="...">
            <condition field="..." operator="..." value="...">
        </group>
    </group>
</filter>
```

I came up with this as the solution.

```
protected override System.Object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
{
    return (this.BaseIndexOf(element));
}
```